# Learning LinkedList and Nodes, but I keep getting a "cannot be resolved or is not in field" error on newNode in buildList method

Tags: java, class, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days, and everything I do is wrong.
I keep getting a "cannot be resolved or is not in field" error for the .next on newNode.next in buildList method.
I am also getting this same error for the .next and the .data on the current.next/ current.data in the printList method.
What I have is what is in the book, but it does not want to work in Eclipse.
Please help...

```
package linkedList;

import java.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class ListOne {
    //This part needs various options:
    //Build list
    //clear list
    //check if the list is sorted
    //insert at head
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Node head;
    public int linkedListCount = 0;
    //public static LinkedList<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    private class MyNode{
        private int data;
        private Node next;

        public MyNode(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
        //BUILD LIST
    public void buildList(int value){
        Node newNode = (Node) new MyNode(value);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
        //Clear the list
    public void clearList(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void printList () {
        if(head == null){
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            // visit
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }  // traversal
    }  // printList


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head == null;
    }
}
```

> Here is the errors I am receiving.
>   In method buildList, on newNode.next = "next cannot be resolved or is not a field." / In method printList, on current.data = "data cannot be resolved or is not a field." / In method printList, on current.next = "next cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Comment: Also, I have a separate driver class with the main method that calls it. Just in case anyone wants to know.

Comment: Post your *complete* error message, everything in it

Comment: For newNode.next = "next cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: For current.data = "data cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: You are casting `MyNode` to `Node`, but `MyNode` does not inherit from `Node`.

Comment: For current.next = "next cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: This information is too important to bury in comments. Please [edit] your question and post the error message in the question. Also your MyNode class would help.

Comment: So, should I just change MyNode to Node? or do I need to make it inherit someway that I do not know?

Comment: Alright, will do.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to get fields from Node? It's an interface and does not have any instance fields. This whole thing is starting to smell. Are you using the right Node type to begin with?

Comment: [Link to Node API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)

Comment: _The Node interface is the primary datatype for the entire Document Object Model._ I don't think it's needed here. Just use `MyNode`.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to this and still learning about Nodes, and this website. I will try this.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any point in using the `Node` interface at all. Just use `MyNode` throughout:

```
package linkedList;

import java.util.*;
//import org.w3c.dom.Node;  No need for this

public class ListOne {
    // .....
    public static MyNode head;
    private class MyNode{
        private int data;
        private MyNode next;

        public MyNode(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    //BUILD LIST
    public void buildList(int value){
        MyNode newNode = new MyNode(value);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    // etc....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was thinking that "Node" was a type, like Integer or something.